# 27" iMac with mini display port and Windows 10 - use in target display mode?

Tags: display, imac, displayport

I have a 27" iMac, with a mini-display port. I do not have MacOS installed on it. Instead I have Windows 10 installed on it. Can I enable target display mode using this configuration?

If not, how could I get into target display mode without removing Windows 10 from the internal hard disk?

Model: Mid 2010 (2.8GHZ QUAD-CORE INTEL CORE I5, ATI RADEON HD 5750)

Comment: Did you already try to reboot and enable target disk mode as usual?

Comment: Sorry but reboot into what? I was under the impression from what I have been reading that target disk mode requires MacOS to be loaded and running?

Comment: Sorry, got confused with Disk and Display...

Comment: Sorry my bad, wrote target disk mode instead of display mode :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for anyone with the same issues. Indeed you need a working copy of MacOS in order to enable Target Display Mode. So using the internet recovery option (Command+R while booting up) I installed MacOS on an external 32GB usb stick attached to my iMac. Then after about an hour of installation the iMac booted into High Sierra and using Command+F2 it switched into Target Display Mode and I was able to use it as a second monitor for my Windows 10 PC.

Comment: What adapter did you use?